# Does audioplayers 5.2.1 for Flutter support Bluetooth remote control:Play, Pause, etc?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, flutter-audioplayers

I have read the Getting Started documentation and the Features Parity Table and I cannot find any references to Bluetooth remote control of the player. Is that because it does not support it or did I just miss it in your documentation?

I am not asking to play the audio over Bluetooth - just control it. The Expo Audio Player for React Native can play audio over Bluetooth but cannot control it. I have tested their audio player on the web and it sends audio to my bluetooth headphones fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you go over the [Getting Started section](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/getting_started.md), you will notice that they state there how to load an audio asset:

> **Sources**
>
> Each AudioPlayer is created empty and has to be configured
> with an audio source (and it can only have one; changing it will
> replace the previous source).
>
> The source (cf. packages/audioplayers/lib/src/source.dart) is
> basically what audio you are playing (a song, sound effect, radio
> stream, etc), **and it can have one of 4 types**:
>
> **UrlSource:**
>
> get the audio from a remote URL from the Internet. This can
> be a direct link to a supported file to be downloaded, or a radio
> stream.
>
> **DeviceFileSource:**
>
> access a file in the user's device, probably
> selected by a file picker.
>
> **AssetSource:**
>
> play an asset bundled with
> your app, by default within the assets directory. To customize the
> prefix, see AudioCache.
>
> **BytesSource (only some platforms):**
>
> pass in the
> bytes of your audio directly (read it from anywhere).

So it does not support playing the audio file from Bluetooth.